# Как связать View, Presenter и Interactor с помощью Rx?

Tags: android, архитектура

Как бы вы поступили, если бы вам, например, требовалось решить задачу с пажинацией или поиском по строке. Что я имею ввиду, у нас есть `RecyclerView` или `SearchView`, пользователь сколлит список или вводит текст.

Как мы должны поступить? Прокидывать события в `презентер`, далее на каждое событие `презентер` вызывает `интерактор` и получает новые данные. Или второй вариант, получаем во View `Observable<Integer>` (для пажинации) или `Observable<String>` (для поиска), которые будут эммитить каждый раз при изменении во `View` оффсета списка или строки поиска. Далее отдаем `Observable` презентеру, который предаст `Observable` как параметр интерактору. Получается, что нужно только один раз вызыать `интерактор`. Тут вопрос другой, как контролировать все это дело, например, на каждое изменение, нужно дополнительно что то показывать во `View` (прогресс бар и т.д.), как лучше это сделать? Навешать операторов на `Observable` в презентере или с интерактора события кидать? Какой вариант вы считаете концептуально правильным, какой удобнее?

Answer (score 2):

Напишу не "как правильно", а "как делаю обычно и какие плюсы".

В случае с поисковой строкой и списком действительно неплохо события отслеживать, подписываясь на них, как на `Observable`. Не могу найти где, но в какой-то из конференций видел доклад об этом подходе. Здесь только (да как и во всем Rx) нельзя забывать отписываться. Способ также хорош тем, что в случае быстрого изменения текста или при "таскании" списка вверх-вниз (часто вызывать событие пагинации) можно воспользоваться замечательным `debounce()` и задержки работают как нужно.

> https://medium.com/@matdziu/using-rxjava-in-searchview-f1d1d5dcb8b7

По поводу передачи `Observable` между слоями. Пусть есть некоторый источник данных (какой-нибудь `repository`, который возвращает `Observable` на запрос данных из БД или сети). Когда пользователь переходит на определенный экран, `View` уведомляет `Presenter` о том, что нужно подгрузить данные, `Presenter` просит у `Interactor`-а `Observable` и подписывается на него. `Interactor` в свою очередь просит у `Repository` этот `Observable` и, прежде чем вернуть его презентеру, навешивает при необходимости различные операторы (фильтры, маппинги и т.д.). Смысл в том, что `View` лишь уведомила `Presenter` о событии, а тот, если данные успели обработаться, а пользователь все еще на этом экране, просто передаст их во `View`.

Если у нас поисковая строка или список, то источником данных становится `View`. Если `View` сама будет кидать `Presenter`-у `Observable`, то это означает, что появилась зависимость, обратная описанной выше. На мой взгляд - не вариант. Я бы создал для поисковой строки или списка `Observable` и предоставил `Presenter`-у самому решать, когда подписываться и отписываться. То есть, при изменении строки или при скролле, Вы не говорите `presenter.onChanged(Observable)`, а просто, при создании `View`, создаете `Observable` на необходимые изменения на экране, а `Presenter` по предоставленному Вами интерфейсу будет подписываться/отписываться на события.

Если я правильно понимаю, то именно такой подход называют реактивной работой с `View`. Таким образом можно создавать `Observable` для любых событий на экране (даже на простое нажатие кнопки), а `Presenter` будет подписываться, когда это будет необходимо. При этом `View` не проявляет явно никакой инициативы по отношению к `Presenter`-у.

Буду рад критике от гуру архитектуры в комментариях.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше мнение! Я некоторое время использовал такой подход, действительно очень удобно использовать оператор debounce. Только я передавал презентереру Observable, я испытывал некоторые проблемы с тем, что при пересоздании View происходит пересоздание Observabl и при повторной подписке происходил лишний эммит, не помню деталей, но с подобными проблемами при таком подходе сталкивались и другие (https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby/blob/master/sample-mvi/src/main/java/com/hannesdorfmann/mosby3/sample/mvi/view/search/SearchFragment.java#L77), а Вы предлагаете держать Observable во View?

Comment: презентер при этом переживал пересоздание View

Comment: А Вы хотите держать observable в презентере, при том что эмитит вью? Здесь ведь не работа с данными как таковыми, а отслеживание событий вью. Такой observable по моему мнению должен быть у источника событий.

Comment: Да, такой вариант рассматривал. Спасибо, мне нужно подумать над этим еще. В подходе реактивной работы со View, несмотря на то что все кажется достаточно простым, на практике что то обязательно пойдет не так =)